# Error 1723 during installation of custom app on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation

I have developed a Windows desktop application in VS 2013, packaged it with InstallShield LE and prepared it as a self-extracting executable. When a customer tried to install on 2 domestic Win 10 machines he received the message

> Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action ISSetAllUsers, entry: SetAllUsers, library: C:\Users...\MSI10B4.tmpBlockquote

Installation proceeded OK on various test machines running Win7, 8  and 10.Simulating the suspected problem by removing write permissions on  c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp caused a different error (1711 - disk error).

I suggested checking permissions on c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp but these gave full control to the installing account. I also suggested running the installer as Administrator. Neither of these actions resolved the problem. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The customer indicated he had resolved the issue by turning off his anti-virus program. It appears to have prevented any installation, not just one with malicious intent.